# Get all values in one vector in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have two arrays, A (500 x 128 integer values) and B (500 x 64 real values). I want to concatenate both to get C. The problem is that Matlab ignores all values in B as they are small values. Is there any way to get all values without neglect?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think they neglected, they are probably just not displayed... Try `C = [A, B]; C(1:10,129:130)`.

Answer (score 4):

I think this can simulate your problem:

```
A = int8(randi(4,4)*10);
B = rand(4,4)*10;
C = [A B] 

C =

  10  20  20  30   3   0   8   3
  40  10  40  40   2   6   1   2
  30  20  10  30   2   1   6   6
  40  20  40  30   9   9   5   5
```

To achieve the result you want, you have to add a type to your data before concatenating them:

```
C = [double(A) B]
C =

 Columns 1 through 7:

   10.00000   20.00000   20.00000   30.00000    2.92979    0.31162    7.73694
   40.00000   10.00000   40.00000   40.00000    1.71392    5.82900    1.08936
   30.00000   20.00000   10.00000   30.00000    1.83903    0.84160    5.75773
   40.00000   20.00000   40.00000   30.00000    8.81039    9.31400    4.60636

 Column 8:

    3.10192
    1.75853
    5.75013
    5.39383
```

So here when you mention that `A` has to be shown as a double matrix, the other matrix, `B` is kept at its original type. You can check the other existing types in MATLAB [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html).

Comment: That's interesting: concatenating integer-type values and double-precision values yields integer-type result

Comment: @LuisMendo: That's somehow a pattern in matlab. Operations of integer and double return an integer. Otherwise it would be annoying to do integer math because lines like `x=x+1` would return a double and not a value of the same type as x.

Comment: And many of us consider that a failing of Matlab.  The default should be (and is, in many other languages) to coerce the operations to the highest precision class presented.  If you don't want to do so, specify explicitly what the inputs are.  E.g. (`R` syntax)   `x = x + 1L`  where "L" means long integer.

Comment: @Daniel Aaah, got it. Yes, it makes a lot of sense

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That's what I thought initially. Perhaps Matlab's behaviour regarding this has to do with the fact that typing is dynamic. As Daniel says, it's intuitive to do `x=x+1` with `x` integer and automatically keep the integer type for `x`